# How to view my contribution points in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Because of [this news](http://thenextweb.com/google/2015/11/16/google-is-giving-away-drive-storage-to-get-more-restaurant-reviews-for-maps/) that Google is now willing to give 1 TB of Google Drive storage to diligent Local Guides, I was encouraged to take photos of places near me, review edits, and make reviews of places that I've been. The problem is that I can't see my contribution points. Do you know where I can find it?

I am looking for a way to view my contribution points using a browser, not for mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 06/18/2016:

Google Maps has been updated. You can easily see your contributions just by going to [www.google.com/maps/contrib](https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/) in your favorite browser on the desktop.

Answer (score 3):

According to the information here: http://google-latlong.blogspot.jp/2015/11/get-your-favorite-places-on-map-with_13.html

> Once you sign-up, download the latest Google Maps update on Android and iPhone to follow your progress on the new Contributions tab. Your total points, level, and to-do list—suggestions for places to contribute to—conveniently appear together in one place.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a limitation that Google has not addressed. The *ONLY* way to view you points is via the mobile app under *Menu* -> *Your Contributions*.  Per Google, please note that they say it may take up to 48 hours for new points to appear on your account.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to [Google maps](http://www.google.com/maps) then click on the hamburger menu. There should be a menu options labeled "Your contributions". From there you should be able to see what you have contributed and work out your points from there.

Alternatively you could emulate an android device using [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at "Your contributions" on the browser-based desktop version of Maps you would not find them.

**Google has not implemented them yet.**

You can only see that on apps.